# Not Possible To Use Multiple LookupRows in a single HTML paste?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

First time poster. I'm trying to use multiple LookupRows in a single HTML Paste. While I don't see anything in the documentation saying that this isn't possible.

```
%%[Set @DE1Result = LookupRows("DE1","USER_LOGIN",USER_LOGIN)
  IF RowCount(@DE1Result) > 0 THEN]%%
  html html html...
  %%[ENDIF]%%

%%[Set @DE2Result = LookupRows("DE2","USER_LOGIN",USER_LOGIN)
  IF RowCount(@DE2Result) > 0 THEN]%%
  html html html...
  %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Using one or the other on its own is able to produce a preview, but using both in the same HTML paste produces the error "Unable to generate preview."

Is it not possible

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible.

First, run `Validate` from the toolbar.  It'll give you some details if there are syntax issues.

Second, assuming your `DE1` and `DE2` Data Extensions exist, I'd wrap your personalization string in an [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue) function.  It'll return an empty string if it doesn't exist (as opposed to blowing up the email):

```
%%[
var @DE1Result, @DE1Result, @USER_LOGIN
set @USER_LOGIN = AttributeValue("USER_LOGIN")
]%%

%%[
Set @DE1Result = LookupRows("DE1","USER_LOGIN",@USER_LOGIN)
IF RowCount(@DE1Result) > 0 THEN
]%%
html html html...
%%[ ENDIF ]%%

%%[
Set @DE2Result = LookupRows("DE2","USER_LOGIN",@USER_LOGIN)
IF RowCount(@DE2Result) > 0 THEN
]%%
html html html...
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Delayed reply as I was able to figure out a similar solution, but your second response was closer to the heart of my issue. Validating didn't produce any syntax errors.